# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0) React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, amazon-s3, promise

I am trying to upload files to AWS S3 bucket from my react native app but I get this error ->
**Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0)**
Here is the code:

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker';
import { RNS3 } from 'react-native-aws3';
import Colors from '../constants/Colors';

const Upload = (props) => {

    async function openDocumentFile() {
        try {
            const res = await DocumentPicker.pickSingle({
                type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles],
            });
            console.log(
                res.uri,
                res.name,
                res.type,
                res.size
            );
            const file = {
                uri: res.uri,
                name: res.name,
                type: res.type,
            }
            const options = {
                keyPrefix: "uploads/",
                bucket: '',
                region: 'ap-south-1',
                accessKey: '',
                secretKey: '',
                successActionStatus: 201
            }
            RNS3.put(file, options)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status !== 201){
                    console.log(response.status);
                  throw new Error("Failed to upload image to S3");
                }
                console.log(response.body);
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            if(DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
                console.log("user cancelled");
            }
            throw err;
        }
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.view}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={openDocumentFile}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Upload Documents</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Upload;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    view: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    button: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        color: Colors.white,
        padding: 10,
        borderColor: Colors.primary,
        borderWidth: 1,
    },
    text: {
        color: Colors.primary,
    }
})
```

Here is the output I get which shows that the file is correctly selected but there is error in the code to upload the file to AWS-S3:

```
LOG content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A31 helloWorld.jpeg image/jpeg 26150
LOG  400
WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Failed to upload image to S3
```

I checked other questions and answers, but I didn't find a solution. How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're surrounding the problematic code with `try`/`catch`, which is good - but then you're re-throwing the error:

```
catch (err) {
    if(DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
        console.log("user cancelled");
    }
    throw err;
}
```

which will result in an unhandled rejection unless there's *another* `try`/`catch` or `.catch` around that.

Only throw if there's something higher up on the call stack that can handle it. In this case, there isn't - `openDocumentFile` should handle everything itself - so don't re-throw in case of there's a problem.

```
catch (err) {
    if(DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
        console.log("user cancelled");
    }
}
```

You also need to properly `await` the call to `RNS3.put` - right now, it's not being waited for, so it's not connected with the `try`/`catch`. This:

```
        RNS3.put(file, options)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status !== 201){
                console.log(response.status);
              throw new Error("Failed to upload image to S3");
            }
            console.log(response.body);
        });
```

should be

```
const response = await RNS3.put(file, options)
if (response.status !== 201){
    console.log(response.status);
    throw new Error("Failed to upload image to S3");
}
console.log(response.body);
```

Generally, don't mix `await` and `.then` unless you understand Promises completely and know what you're doing - otherwise, to avoid confusing yourself, I'd recommend using only one or the other in a particular segment of code. Either `await` (and `try`/`catch`), or use `.then`, but not both in the same section of asynchronous logic.